# sql queries returning NULL values when echoed

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, null

I'm getting null for all of these php functions:

```
echo gettype($row);

echo gettype($foo);

echo gettype($foo1);

echo gettype($oldstring);

echo gettype($oldstring2);

echo gettype($changedstring);

echo gettype($changedstring2);
```

The code worked when I didn't do all the queries, and I just used it as a form to input values into. Except now, I need to use php with my form to display certain values.

I've also double checked my database under the corresponding columns, and they do have correct and full values. The queries did work on a different page, but it's showing null on this page.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

    if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
    {
    $errorMessage="";

    if (empty($_POST['camperpickedup'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .="<li>You forgot to select whether the camper is being picked up!</li>";
    }
    if (empty($_POST['personPickingUpCamper'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage ="<li>You forgot to enter the person picking up the camper!</li>";
    }

    $_SESSION['camperpickedup'] = $_POST['camperpickedup'];
    $_SESSION['personPickingUpCamper'] = $_POST['personPickingUpCamper'];

    $db = mysql_connect(
  ':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
  'root',
  'root'
);
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db('onlineform', $db);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT newPrice,numberOfWeeks FROM onlineformdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT newCampSessions FROM onlineformdata ORDER BY id DESC    LIMIT 1") or die('Error ' . mysql_error());
$foo = mysql_fetch_array($query1);

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT pricePerWeek FROM onlineformdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die('Error ' . mysql_error());
$foo1 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);

$oldstring = $foo['newCampSessions'];
$oldstring2 = $foo1['pricePerWeek'];

$changedstring = unserialize($oldstring);
$changedstring2 = unserialize($oldstring2);

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js">
    </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">var jslang='EN';
     </script>
     <link href="http://activemindandbody.orgStyleSheets/ModuleStyleSheets.css" rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" />
     <script type="text/javascript">var jslang='EN';
        </script>
        <link href="http://activemindandbody.org/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.04022.js"></script>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700,300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- BC_OBNW -->
        <div id="container">
        <div id="header"><div id="header_text" style="top: 118px; left: 23px;">
            <p>Make a donation today and help&nbsp;&nbsp;âCreating a Brighter Future                      
    Together.â&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="http://activemindandbody.org/donation.html">Make a donation now !</a> </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
<section class="tabs">

<input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-1" checked="checked" />

     <label for="tab-1" class="tab-label-1">1. Camper's Info</label>

     <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-2" />
     <label for="tab-2" class="tab-label-2">2. Parent's Info</label>

    <input id="tab-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-3" />
    <label for="tab-3" class="tab-label-3">3. Emergency<br/> Contacts</label>

    <input id="tab-4" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-4" />
    <label for="tab-4" class="tab-label-4">4. Camper's Ride Home</label>

    <input id="tab-5" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-5" />
    <label for="tab-5" class="tab-label-5">5. <br/> Camp Days & Prices</label>

    <input id="tab-6" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-6" />
    <label for="tab-6" class="tab-label-6">6. Confirm your details</label>

    <input id="tab-7" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-7" />
    <label for="tab-7" class="tab-label-7">7. <br />Paypal</label>
                    </section>

    <div class="clear-shadow"></div>
    <div class="content indent">

<form id="paymentform" action="amd8.php" method="post">
    <br />
   <label><b>Camp Sessions: 1-6 (Check off the week(s) the camper will be participating in.)</b> </label><br /><br />
   <ol>
   <?php  
for ($count = 0; $count < $row[1]; $count++)
        {
            echo"<li>"; echo $changedstring[$count]; echo '($'; echo $changedstring2[$count]; echo '/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="'; echo $changedstring[$count]; echo "></li>;";
        }

        echo gettype($row);
        echo gettype($foo);
        echo gettype($foo1);
        echo gettype($oldstring);
        echo gettype($oldstring2);
        echo gettype($changedstring);
        echo gettype($changedstring2);

?>
   <li>July 8 - July 12 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July8-July12" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek1"></li>
   <li>July 15 - July 19 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July15-July19" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek2"></li>
   <li>July 22 - July 26 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July22-July26" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek3"></li>
   <li>July 29 - August 2 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July29-August2" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek4"></li>
   <li>August 6 - August 9 ($60/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="August6-August9" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek5"></li>
  <li>August 12 - August 16 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="August12-August16" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek6"></li>
   </ol>

   <label> <b> Include After Camp Care? </b></label> <input type="checkbox" name= "campcare" onclick="getTotal()" id="aftercampcare" /> <br /><br />
   <i> After Camp Care is available from 4pm-6pm for an additional charge of $2/hr.</i><br /><br />

      Total Price: $<span class="totalPrice"> </span>
      <br/><br/>

 <input type="hidden" name="totalprice" />  
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" class="button greenButton"/>
<input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="button redButton" onclick="href='activemindandbody.org'">

</form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Step 1. this goes at the top of the php document. ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Yeah I tried that, doesn't show anything except the number 1 when I echo it.

Comment: No, you do not echo this.

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: formSubmit in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/amd7.php on line 4
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0052 241240 {main}( ) ../amd7.php:0

Comment: BAMF. Problem solved. Your entire sql logic is wrapped in a boolean check that fails.

Comment: caught it, yeah sorry about that. terrible sleep last night :p

Comment: so what type of errors can you use this for?

Comment: @JohnSmith Please consider deleting this question

Comment: You should always check for the existence of a post value before using it. If it doesn't exist, a redirect is usually in order. It might be worth taking the time to learn a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL logic is wrapped in a boolean check form $_POST['formSubmit'] that fails.

Comment: err actually, I closed the if statement so it doesn't affect the queries. However, it's still giving me the same problems

Comment: hmm, all you did was move the bracket down, right before I connect to my database right? and if it does work for you, does my foreach loop work correctly?